# How do I add nested routes in root/home view with React Router v4?

Tags: react-router

Following this instruction: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic

Simply to say, I want move all the **nested views** from **Topics** to **Home**.

As you can see, **Topics** menu has nested views and the nested views are resolved by the matched path, like `\topics\rendering`, `\topics\components` etc. 
however in my case, I'd like to put all those nested views into Home menu, since Home menu is the root path `/`, so it doesn't seem to work anymore.

Below is what I expected,

```
const BasicExample = () => (
  <Router>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/about">About</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/topics">Topics</Link></li>
      </ul>

      <hr/>

      <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
      <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
      <Route path="/topics" component={Topics}/>
    </div>
  </Router>
)

const Home = ({ match }) => (
  <div>
    <h2>Home</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <Link to={`${match.url}/rendering`}>
          Rendering with React
        </Link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link to={`${match.url}/components`}>
          Components
        </Link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link to={`${match.url}/props-v-state`}>
          Props v. State
        </Link>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <Route path={`${match.url}/:desc`} component={SubHome}/>
    <Route exact path={match.url} render={() => (
      <h3>Please select.</h3>
    )}/>
  </div>
)

const SubHome = ({ match }) => (
  <div>
    <h3>{match.params.desc}</h3>
  </div>
)
```

However this doesn't work, I guess it could be caused by the home owns the root path `/`.

Comment: Cannot understand your question. You have to re-phrase it in a better way.

Comment: @Panther thanks, I've add some more explanations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find an official solution for my case, so I made a workaround.

I gave the **Home** menu a path like `/home` rather than `/`, and since the app will start with `/` initially, so I added a redirection above, the simple code as below,

```
const BasicExample = () => (
  <Router>
    <div>
      <Redirect from="/" to="/home" /> 
      <ul>
        <li><Link to="/home">Home</Link></li> 
        <li><Link to="/about">About</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/topics">Topics</Link></li>
      </ul>

      <hr/>

      <Route exact path="/home" component={Home}/>
      <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
      <Route path="/topics" component={Topics}/>
    </div>
  </Router>
)

const Home = ({ match }) => (
  <div>
    <h2>Home</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <Link to={`${match.url}/rendering`}>
          Rendering with React
        </Link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link to={`${match.url}/components`}>
          Components
        </Link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link to={`${match.url}/props-v-state`}>
          Props v. State
        </Link>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <Route path={`${match.url}/:desc`} component={SubHome}/>
    <Route exact path={match.url} render={() => (
      <h3>Please select.</h3>
    )}/>
  </div>
)

const SubHome = ({ match }) => (
  <div>
    <h3>{match.params.desc}</h3>
  </div>
)
```